# sumar columnas con php

Tags: php

estoy generando un código que lee datos de Excel y los muestra con las librerías de phpExcel. ahora quiero que sume las columnas de cada cliente y muestre el resultado donde dice total

[image: esta es la tabla que lee del excel]

y el código es el siguiente.

```
Echo '<table border=1><tr>
<td>Nombre Usuario</td>
<td>Copias B/N</td>
<td>Copia Color</td>
<td>Copia Color</td>
<td>Copia Color</td>
<td>Impresion B/N</td>
<td>Impresion Color</td>
<td>SCANER B/N </td>
<td>SCANER Color </td>
<td>SCANER DD B/N </td>
<td>SCANER DD Color </td>
<td>SCANER DD 2Color </td>
<td>TOTAL </td></tr>';


for($fila =2; $fila<= $highestRow; $fila++){
    
    $A = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $B = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $E = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $H = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $K = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('K'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $N = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('N'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $Q = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('Q'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $AL = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('AL'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $AO = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('AO'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $BA = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('BA'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $BD = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('BD'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    $BG = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('BG'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();
    
   
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $A.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $B.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $E.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $H.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $K.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $N.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $Q.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $AL.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $AO.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $BA.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $BD.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $BG.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

}
```

la suma la estoy realizando con un for y un contador.

```
$TOTAL=0;
for($ROW =2; $ROW<= $highestRow; $ROW++){ 
    $A = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$fila)->getCalculatedValue();      
}
   ECHO " EL RESULTADO ES .$TOTAL";
```

Comment: Pero ¿cuál es el problema o error?

Comment: el for no esta realizando la suma de las columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que efectúes la suma de cada cliente desde SQL, así únicamente tienes que imprimir el resultado
Se puede efectuar con un `CASE` desde SQL